# 20.04 LTS, today it asked me to update to 5.8.0.34 from 5.4.0.59 and it broke LSI 2116

Tags: kernel

Not sure why just today, after months of running on 20.04 LTS, it asked me to update to 5.8.0.34. But anyway, I did, rebooted, and never saw any of the disks attached to an LSI 2116 controller any more. Poked around, decided to reboot into 5.4.0.59 and it worked fine, disks there. In case of a one time glitch, went back to 5.8, and, no disks. Couldn't find a way to make them appear. So, now I have removed HWE (again not sure why just now asked me to update, did not intentionally install it). But don't know why that kernel won't see disks attached to the LSI, surely that controller would still be supported?

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe I found the kernel bug. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209177 I applied the boot param, and, it does work. I did rebuild initramfs, no difference. Hopefully the bug will eventually be fixed, but for now, I put `mpt3sas.max_queue_depth=10000` in `/etc/default/grub.d/myfile.cfg` so that it will run correctly.